# What does "event handled in markup" mean?

Tags: asp.net, events, vb.net

I ran into a problem after one of my function in VB.Net was not executing nor was it giving me an error,  and someone recommended me to check if "The server-side event is handled both in markup and in code behind"
Could anyone please explain what does server-side event handled in markup mean please, couldn't find anything about it on google.

Comment: Please share your code here so that we can see if there is something wrong.

Comment: Handled in markup means the event is hoocked in the aspx file:  <asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddCategoryId_SelectedIndexChanged"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may have been referring to how the event handler is bound to a control. In markup you can specify the event as a property on the control:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

But you can also use the Handles keyword in code behind to bind to the control:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
```

Having them both set can have unforeseen problems.

Comment: Thank you mate, could have never understood by myself.